# One dataframe to the power of another dataframe of different dimensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Is it possible to use the .pow() function or is there a way of doing this without having to iterate through every column?
I have to dataframes one of the form:

```
                Variable_1        Variable_2  ...         Variable_n
Base              1.432             1.687     ...           1.943
```

And another

```
         Variable_1      Variable_2     ...       Variable_n
Sample_1    13                  15      ...           3
Sample_2    14                   9      ...          19
Sample_3    25                  21      ...          17
Sample_4    15                  23      ...          21
  ...      ...                 ...      ...         ...
Sample_m    12                   5      ...           4
```

There will always be the same column names for both dataframes but they might be in different orders, so I want the Base for Variable_1 to be raised to the power of each of the samples.
For Sample_1 = 1.432^13, Sample_2 = 1.432^14 etc.

Also if one of the Variables is missing a value in the Base dataframe, can I pre-select what value it should treat it as?

I tried to use the pow function but it didn't seem to work when:

```
samples.pow(base)
```

tried both axis=0 and axis=1: Gave NaN for all the cells and the final df looked like:

```
                 Variable_1        Variable_2     ...         Variable_n
Base                   NaN             NaN        ...             NaN            
Sample_1               NaN             NaN        ...             NaN            
Sample_2               NaN             NaN        ...             NaN
```

Combining both dataframes, rather than just having samples and variables, it also has Base.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on Jupyter:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Variable1': [1.1], 'Variable2': [1.2], 'Variable3': [1.3]}, index=['Base'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Variable1': [1,2,3,4], 'Variable2': [2,3,4,5], 'Variable3': [3,4,5,6]}, index=['s1','s2','s3','s4'])
tmp = pow(df1.iloc[0], df2)
df1 = df1.append(tmp)
```

DataFrame1:

```
    Variable1   Variable2   Variable3
Base      1.1         1.2         1.3
```

DataFrame2:

```
   Variable1    Variable2   Variable3
s1         1            2           3
s2         2            3           4
s3         3            4           5
s4         5            6           7
```

The output:

```
        Variable1   Variable2   Variable3
  Base     1.1000     1.20000    1.300000
    s1     1.1000     1.44000    2.197000
    s2     1.2100     1.72800    2.856100
    s3     1.3310     2.07360    3.712930
    s4     1.4641     2.48832    4.826809
```

Without for loop and every sample# are power of the base.

Answer (score 0):

For a vectorized solution, you can use joins. First, let's get your data

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO as sio

Base = pd.read_csv(sio("""
                         Variable_1        Variable_2          Variable_n
Base              1.432             1.687              1.943

"""), sep='\s+')

sampl =  pd.read_table(sio("""
                 Variable_1      Variable_2      Variable_n
Sample_1    13                  15               3
Sample_2    14                   9           19
Sample_3    25                  21          17
Sample_4    15                  23           4
"""), sep='\s+')
```

Then we can do a cross join:

```
cross_df = Base.assign(key=1).merge(sampl.assign(key=1), on='key', how='left').drop(columns='key')
```

And create the needed columns looping through all the columns

```
for i in Base.columns:
    cross_df[f'{i}_pow'] = cross_df[f'{i}_x'].pow(cross_df[f'{i}_y'])

cross_df.columns = [i.replace('_y','_Sample').replace('_x','_Base') for i in cross_df.columns]
```

[image]